# Prevent textbox from overwriting previous data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two `if-else` conditions which will display some text on a `Windows Forms` textbox. This textbox has text set to it from a different thread other than the UI thread.

**Context:**

```
 delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

 private void SetText(string text)
 {
     if (this.txtMessages.InvokeRequired)
     {
         SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
         this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
     }
     else
     {
         this.txtMessages.Text = text;
     }
 }

 private void setTextFunc()
 {
     if(this condition is true)
     {
         setText("Hello from text 1" + Environment.NewLine);
     }
     else
     {
         setText("Hello from text 2" + Environment.NewLine);
     }
}
```

Now the problem is that when `Hello from text 2` text gets displayed, it overwrites the first text. I want it to go below and keep the first text.
How can I achieve this?

I thought about using a list collection as so:

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();
listOfStrings.Add("Hello from text 1");
listOfStrings.Add("Hello from text 2");
```

Then iterating through this list collection. Will that do?

```
foreach(string x in listOfStrings)
{
    MessageBox.Show(x);
}
```

Any suggestions? I considered a `RichTextBox` but seeing as I won't be editing the text at runtime, I see no need for it.

Comment: May be you will use `RichTextBox`? Or turn on `Multiline` on `TextBox` and use `+=`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you have is that:

```
this.txtMessages.Text = text;
```

In your `setText` method *replaces* the content of the `Text` property of your text field. If you want to add to the existing content, you should replace the code with something along the lines of:

```
this.txtMessages.Text = this.txtMessages.Text + text;
```

As your code suggests (thanks to the addition of `Environment.NewLine` in `setTextFunc`) that you always want to delimit the newly added text with a line-break, consider adding a new function along the lines of:

```
private void AppendText(string text)
{
    // Code to trigger the Invoke here
    else
    {
        this.txtMessages.Text = this.txtMessages.Text + Environment.newLine + text;
    }
}
```

Doing this also allows you to encapsulate the behaviour of "add text with a new line" into a single method - at the moment your `setTextFunc` method has a *really small* amount of repeated code (adding `Environment.NewLine`) which you can elide by doing this.

Comment: @Harold_Finch, glad it helped =) I've just updated the answer with a smidge more detail.

Comment: this.txtMessages.Text += text;

Comment: @Schuere, agreed, but not seeing usage of `+=` in the OPs code, I elected to keep it simple and make the change in code behaviour I was highlighting as apparent as possible =)

Comment: @Rob, I was thinking of posting my answer. But since yours was more complete I simply posted a comment to demonstrate that this also could be solved with adding an extra character. I'm not aware of the OP's knowledge so that's also a second reason.